# Creating an email "To:" user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I need a selectable text control like many email client programs use for their "To" address fields. It should have the same functionality like being able to delete the complete item etc.

How should I start from building my own control like this? I need this type of control with each item bounded with "<<__>>" operators.

I've attached an image for better explanation.

[image: Selectable address field items]

Answer (score 1):

I would start by familiarizing yourself with how to create [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Next, I'd break the problem up into the components you see.  The top-level user control looks like a Label ("TO:"), a Panel that will contain other controls, and a Button ("+").

It looks like inside the Panel control you will have more UserControls, or perhaps a sub-classed TextBox, that represent each email address.  The Panel control itself will need to be automatically resized depending on the number if controls inside it.

For the actual email address controls you need list the functionality you need and then determine if you can just modify a TextBox slightly, or if you need to combine other controls like labels, buttons, textboxes to achieve the result you want.